# How to plot mixed-frequency series with NAs in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe `x`:

```r
x1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), 
                           as.Date("2012-12-01"), 
                           by = "month"), 
                TS1 = rnorm(36,0,1), 
                TS2 = rnorm(36,0,1), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)

x2 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), 
                           as.Date("2012-12-01"), 
                           by = "quarter"), 
                TS3 = rnorm(12,0,1), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)

x <- left_join(x1, x2, by = "Date")
```

`x` contains two monthly series, while one is quarterly.

I would like to plot all three series at the same time with `ggplot`. I am aware of `dualplot` as a way to do it. The issue with it however is that it allows you to plot only 2 mixed frequency series.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ggplot` requires long format, so we first use `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

Next, we can plot `TS1` and `TS2` easily, but `TS3` will not plot at all as it contains missing values.

One option is to plot the line with missings with a separate `geom_line` call:

```r
x2 <- x %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(TS1, TS2, TS3), names_to = "TS") %>%
  mutate(TS = as.factor(TS))

ggplot(x2, aes(x = Date, y = value, group = TS, color = TS)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(data = subset(x2, TS == "TS3" & !is.na(value)))
```

[image]

Comment: nice solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, `ggplot` does not *have to* have the data transformed into long format (although it is a nice solution, if you are familiar with transforming data, and recommended especially if there were lots of columns or separate lines to be plotted).

For simplicity, especially when learning `ggplot` can I propose an alternative solution.

`TS1` and `TS2` can easily be plotted against date, as neither have `NA` values. Here, we call `geom_line()` twice, once for each line:

```
x %>%  
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(Date, TS1), colour = 'red')+
  geom_line(aes(Date, TS2), colour = 'blue')
```

[image]

If you try and include a third `geom_line()` with `TS3`, only the original two lines are plotted due to `TS3`'s missing values (`NA`). A solution is to fill in the `NA` values in the data before plotting, using `zoo::na.approx()`. As the name suggests, `zoo::na.approx()` is able to approximate values when you have `NA`s, by linear interpolation. In this instance, I assume linear interpolation between known values is appropriate for plotting (as `geom_line` is doing anyway). Check out `?zoo::na.approx` for more details, including non-linear interpolation.

`zoo::na.approx(TS3, Date, na.rm = FALSE)` may be read aloud like: "We want to approximate the values of `TS3` when they are missing (`NA`), based on the values of `Date`, and if there are still `NA`s in the interpolated data keep the non-`NA` values we *can* approximate."

```
x %>%
  mutate(
    TS3 = zoo::na.approx(TS3, Date, na.rm = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(Date, TS1), colour = 'red')+
  geom_line(aes(Date, TS2), colour = 'blue')+
  geom_line(aes(Date, TS3), colour = 'green')
```

[image]

Note that the green line finishes just short (2 data points) of the other two lines. This is because by default, `zoo::na.approx()` doesn't interpolate when `NA` is not between two known data points. This is why we specified `na.rm = FALSE` when doing the interpolation. Look at the help page `?zoo::na.approx` for alternatives (such as repeating the last known observation).